# Interpretation of apt depends output

Tags: apt

When running an example of `apt depends` command, e.g.

```
$ apt depends nginx
nginx
 |Depends: nginx-core (<< 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2.1~)
 |Depends: nginx-full (<< 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2.1~)
 |Depends: nginx-light (<< 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2.1~)
  Depends: nginx-extras (<< 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2.1~)
 |Depends: nginx-core (>= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2)
 |Depends: nginx-full (>= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2)
 |Depends: nginx-light (>= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2)
  Depends: nginx-extras (>= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2)
```

what is the meaning of the `|` symbol in the beginning of some of the listed dependencies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pipe introduces alternate dependencies: `nginx` depends on one of `nginx-core`, `nginx-full`, `nginx-light`, or `nginx-extras`. The doubles dependencies are used to specify a version range. (The completely dependency constraints aren’t visible here, which suggests that they are insufficient — but `nginx-core`, `-full`, `-light`, and `-extras` conflict with each other, which ensures that the “or” in the set of dependencies is an “exclusive or”.)

You’ll see this more clearly if you look at the output of `apt show nginx`.